# How can I implement "Cookie Opt-In" in a JavaServer Faces application?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets, cookies

To implement the EU Cookie Law in a stateful JavaServer Faces web application I would like to notify the user about cookie usage with an opt-in dialog. Creating the opt-in dialog with JSF, and storing the opt-in as a cookie are easy to implement.

One detail however raises a technical question:

- **When a users visits the web page the first time, no cookies must be sent. How do I suppress the transmission of JSESSIONID?** - Can this be done with a Servlet filter without breaking the JavaServer Faces request processing?

Comment: If I remember correctly, if the client doesn't support cookies, JSESSIONID will be sent back in url of the Location header, so it should work out of the box. EDIT: but that can't be used with opt-in, sorry, my bad

Comment: @PredragMaric we cannot assume that the client visits the web app with cookie support disabled - clients may want to use cookies on other pages

Comment: I don't see why a filter would break FacesServlet. Have you tried it?